# Select rows in SQL with regex values that match input?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Rather than selecting rows based on whether their string value equals a given regular expression input, I want to select rows with regular expressions that match a given string input.

As far as purpose, I'm am trying to identify website names from input URLs.

```
TABLE
WEBSITE                    REGEX 
The New York Times         ^.+\.nytimes.com.*$
```

Is there a good way to do this? I'm using postgres, and I was hoping to avoid large loops.

Thanks!

Comment: From what I can tell, you should just be able to do `SELECT * FROM TABLE where 'http://www.nytimes.com/foo/' ~ REGEX` - Though I admit I haven't actually tried it.

Comment: A simple google search with "postgres regex" shows several results explaining how to do that already among the first few results.

Comment: Update - Just tried it, works fine..  Posted example below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```
CREATE TABLE Sites
(
   SiteName text,
   RegEx text  
);

INSERT INTO Sites VALUES ('NY Times', '^.+\.nytimes.com.*$');
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM Sites
WHERE 'http://www.nytimes.com/Foo' ~ RegEx;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cad75/1)

Keep in mind this might start to get slow if you had a lot of rows, as it's going to have to do a sequential table scan each time *and* run the regular expression against each row.  A better approach might be to parse the URL first and normalize it in some way, then look for an exact match in the table.

Comment: I would likely have between 1,000 and 1,500 rows. I need the select output to appear very quickly to end user - it will be initiated via ajax. Do you think this would be "laggy" from UX point of view?

Comment: With 1,000 - 1,500?  Probably not *too* bad, computers are pretty fast these days and you can probably wrap it in an [IMMUTABLE or STABLE function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-volatility.html) so everything could be cached.

Comment: What would be the MS SQL equivalent of this? I can't find anything related to SQL Server 2012